# The set of all matrices of full rank is an open set

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $m<n$ and let $M(m\times n,\mathbb{R})$ be he set of all $m\times n$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb{R}$. Let $M_{m}$ be the subset of $M(m\times n,\mathbb{R})$ consisting of the matrices of rank $m$. Show that $M_{m}$ is an open subset of $M(m\times n,\mathbb{R})$. I know from Linear Algebra that an element of $M_{m}$ must have an invertible $m\times m$  submatrix. I am pretty sure that this fact, along with the fact that the set of invertible $m\times m$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb{R}$, $GL(m,\mathbb{R})$, is an open set, is used in the proof, but I cant connect them together.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $F$ be the function taking $ A \in M(m \times n) $ to the $F(A)  = \Sigma_ B  \left | det(B)  \right |   $ where the Sigma runnig over all m by m sub matrices of A. Clearly $F$ is continuous so $F^{ -1} (R \setminus \{ 0 \}  )$ is an open set is  $ M(m \times n) $

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Note that an $m\times n$ matrix is of full row rank if and only if some of its $m\times m$ submatrix is invertible. Also, note that any union of open sets is open.